# How to map values to table in Javascript left to right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-design

I am trying to fill a table given variables a user provides. 
For example, the user will input N=10 , then an Incremental value I = 2, a max value M = 20 and it should populate a table to read from the bottom left to right like so:

16  18  20

10  12  14

How can I map the values to the cells in the table? I've been finding examples but they are mostly given sets of data in an array of objects.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQQwdd

```js
const BottomLeftValue = 10;
const IncrementalValue = 2;
const MaxValue = 30;

class TableRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      data
    } = this.props;
    const row = data.map((data) =>
    <tr>
      <td key={data.name}>{data.id}</td>
      <td key={data.price}>{data.id+1}</td>
      <td key={data.id}>{data.id+2}</td>
    </tr>
    );
    return (
      <span>{row}</span>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <TableRow data={this.props.data} />
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table data={BottomLeftValue} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

I get that it's not working because there's no data, no name, price, id etc. Trying to work off the closest example I had.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is three columns fixed?

Comment: @norbertpy good question. in my case, it's actually a 5x5 table, and every cell after the max value should be red. I didn't include it here because I wanted to reduce a bit of complexity, but if you have an idea that includes those parameters that would be awesome!

Comment: Frankly this has nothing to do with react. It's basic javascript. You need to create an array of values between min and max for each step and then chunk the resulting array into 3 or whatever column count you have. If that's where you're stuck I highly recommend rephrasing the question and remove all react-specific code.

Comment: @norbertpy Thank you, actually framing it like that helps me figure out what I should be doing. I keep making this problem more complicated than it is in my head.

Answer (score 1):

If making the array and chunking it up is where you're stuck at, this might give you some idea:

```
const min = 10;
const step = 2;
const max = 30;

const getRange = (min, max, step, r =[]) =>
  min <= max
    ? getRange(min + step, max, step, [...r, min])
    : r;


const chunk = (n, arr) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    var last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    return last.length === n 
      ? (acc.push([cur]), acc)
      : (last.push(cur), acc[acc.length - 1] = last, acc);
  }, [[]]);


const range = getRange(min, max, step);
const data = chunk(3, range);

console.log(data); // [ [10, 12, 14], [16, 18, 20], [22, 24, 26], [28, 30] ]

// rendering in react
data.map(row => 
  <div className='row'>
    { row.map(col => 
      <div className='column'>
        { col }
      </div>) 
    }
  </div>
);
```

If you have `lodash` or something similar then you can just use [`_.range`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#range) and [`_.chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chunk)

Comment: I tried to put this straight into my code and the array keeps coming back empty or hits an overflow error (with min = 2, max = 40, step =10) I tried making a codepen, would you mind looking at it? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQQwdd

Comment: @jenryb, I hate codepen :) here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fc273y) version.

Comment: wow stackblitz is way better. Thanks for introducing me! Here's my attempt at the whole scenario: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kv51fm?file=App.js